# Update project running on the cluster

Tags: build-automation, high-availability, apache-zookeeper, openstack

I am running a project on OpenStack cluster of CentOS6.2 machines. Project consists of about 10 git repos. One repo for a service. And services are running on 20 different nodes based on some roles. So, we can do some kind of mapping between services and roles.
Delivering changes through the cluster is a pain in the ass if you are doing it manually. Currently, we are using git pull combined with some configuration changes on each node.
there is a human factor involved, so I don't want to put the cluster offline due to manual error.

I am looking for a solution to deliver changes to the cluster with ability to post configure something after you update the sources (run db migration or configuration files update). Any good solutions on that?

UPDATE:
Projects below seem to fit. Any practical experience with these?

- Zookeper: http://zookeeper.apache.org/
- Doozerd: https://github.com/ha/doozerd
- Noah: https://github.com/lusis/Noah

Answer (score 1):

We use Springloops to manage our deployments.  It allows us to configure different servers for each branch of each repository.  You simply push to the central repository and manage deployment from there.  Deployment can be automated or manual.

There is some support for executing custom callbacks, so you could set up a URL endpoint somewhere in your cluster (can be on a per-project basis) which accepts notifications that pushes have been made which can trigger off your custom scripting.

This works well because it takes the responsibility of source control management out of the servers, if a new deployment to a new server is required it's very easy to add a new server in Springloops and push to it, rather than having to clone a git repository on each new server and configure some cron or triggered task to update the repo.

There are numerous other possible combinations of command line tools and third party managed services, but we've tried a few and Springloops is more than acceptable for managing deployments of the dozens of projects we're currently working on.

It's worth looking into.

Comment: springloops looks like a bit different project: with timesheets, issuetracker and else. The only feature that can be helpful is webhooks management.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like at the scale you're working on, you might be able to make good use of something like [`chef`](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or [`puppet`](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet).

Comment: They are good for provisioning like when you do an initial deployment on that scale. I am not sure if they can be considered as appropriate mechanism for project update.

Answer (score 0):

These projects seem to fit more:

- Zookeper: http://zookeeper.apache.org/
- Doozerd: https://github.com/ha/doozerd
- Noah: https://github.com/lusis/Noah

I am currently thinking of a `Fabric` script with `Dozzerd` as a configuration storage \ master election mechanism.